# Issue with Google Test in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest

I am trying to use Visual Studio 2017 to create a C++ project and then test it with Google Test. I followed this guide to create my project and set Google Test for it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-google-test-for-cpp

My solution has two projects Matrix and Matrix-Test (Google Test project). Project Matrix contains a class called Table. Project Matrix-Test contains a single test where a Table object is declared. Everything looks like this:
[image]

If I try to build the solution I get the following errors[image]:

However, if I don't declare the Table object in the test, then the solution builds successfully.
[image]

Please let me know if you have any idea why I get these errors. Thank you!

Comment: It's been a while since I did VisualStudio, but your Matrix project should be configured to create a library (.lib) output. And then your Matrix-Test needs to link using this library, which will fix the linker errors.

Comment: Based on your suggestion I tried to create static library project instead of a regular console application and add Google Test to it. It built without any errors. Maybe you can post as an answer for how to configure a console application project to create the library (.lib).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The walkthrough https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=vs-2017 will guide you through the process of making your project *Matix* a static library.

Then you can add this library (e.g. Matrix.lib) as an input to the linker in the *Matrix-Test* project. This will solve the *unresolved external symbol* error in regard to your *Table* class.